# How to reinit singleton in Hilt (Android)?

Tags: android, singleton, retrofit, retrofit2, dagger-hilt

I have Hilt DI framework in my Android project. Also I have retrofit, and ApiNetworkModule for getting singleton retrofit object:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public class ApiNetworkModule {
...
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Retrofit provideRetrofit(
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient,
            Gson gson,
            SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager
    ) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl(sharedPrefManager.getUrl())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
...
}
```

In general it works fine, but I have noticed in the case when url is updated in `sharedPrefManager`, retrofit object does not know about it and uses old url. It will be fully updated only after closing-opening application. Is there any way how to reinit `Retrofit` singleton programmatically? Or how to handle it correctly?

Comment: Can you use application context to getUrl and create SharedPreference every time using that context? Then It will give updated baseurl.

Comment: @AbdullahJaved no, it will not work. Retrofit object will be created only once and even when url will be changed in sharedPreferences, Retrofit will not be reinitialized.

Comment: I'm currently using it in my project to get the current app language from preferences for header. And it's working.

Comment: Can you please attach the code, how it looks? Because in the code from my post, Retrofit object definitely will not be recreated

Answer (score -1):

The way to receive the Retrofit object with the modified URL is to remove @Singleton . If you remove @Singleton, you can create a Retrofit object by applying the modified URL to sharedPreferences because a Retrofit object is created and injected when creating a repository.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent.class)
public class ApiNetworkModule {
...
  
    @Provides
    public Retrofit provideRetrofit(
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient,
            Gson gson,
            SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager
    ) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .baseUrl(sharedPrefManager.getUrl())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
...
}
```

We recommend this method because what you want is a way for a new object to be created and injected when there is a modified URL, rather than a Retrofit object that exists only in the singleton component dependency tree.

------------------- UPDATE------------------------------------------

When using SingletonComponent.class, it cannot be initialized because its life cycle is the same as Application. First, as I said, if you remove @Singleton, you can convert, but there is a problem with re-creation, so I will tell you how to change the Api Url address using Interceptor.

```
class HostSelectionInterceptor: Interceptor {
private val baseHost = TestApp.getPreference().getRestUrl().toHttpUrl().host

override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
    val request = chain.request()

    if (TestApp.getPreference().isTestMode()) {
        val convertUrl = when (request.url.host) {
            baseHost -> {
                APIClient.BASE_TEST_REST_URL
            }
            else -> baseHost
        }

        val newUrl = request.url.newBuilder().host(convertUrl.toHttpUrl().host).build()
        val newRequest = request.newBuilder().url(newUrl).build()
        return chain.proceed(newRequest)
    }

    return chain.proceed(request)
    }
}
```

Network.class

```
private val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient by lazy {
    OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor(logInterceptor)
        .addInterceptor(HostSelectionInterceptor())
        .connectTimeout(TIMEOUT_CONNECT, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(TIMEOUT_READ, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(TIMEOUT_WRITE, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
}
```

Interceptor can intercept server requests and responses and perform desired actions. The above example is an example of requesting to change the Base Url to Test Url in Test Mode.

I hope this helps.